# Drop images from a database

Tags: python, java, discord, bots, drop

I want to make a new bot to collect cards in discord (e.g. ningning bot) but I can't find what the code is to drop a letter, could someone help me? Thank you in advance! I'm new to this, sorry.

I confess that I haven't tried any code because I can't think of which one I could use

But I'll try all the codes/methods

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.